# What maintainance is going on there?

Tags: discussion, login

When I tried to access StackOverflow.com I got the following message:

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon.

Mainly what is the maintenance the Stack Exchange Team is doing ?

[image]

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/443415225614995456

Comment: *Necessary* maintainance [sic].